# XmlSerializer escapes an added escape character

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm using the `XmlSerializer` to output a `class` to a `.xml` file.  For the most part, this is working as expected and intended.  However, as a requirement, certain characters need to be removed from the values of the data and replaced with their proper escape characters.

In the elements I need to replace values in, I'm using the `Replace()` method and returning the updated string.  The code below shows this string replacement; the lines commented out are because the `XmlSerializer` already escapes those particular characters.

I have a requirement from a third-party to escape `&`, `<`, `>`, `'`, and `"` characters when they appear within the values of the XML elements.  Currently the characters `&`, `<`, and `>` are being escaped appropriately through the `XmlSerializer`.

The error received when these characters are present is:

> Our system has detected a potential threat in the request message attachment.

However, when I serialize the XML Document after performing the string replace, the `XmlSerializer` sees the `&` character in `&apos;` and makes it `&amp;apos;`.  I think this is a correct functionality of the `XmlSerializer` object.  However, I would like the serializer to either **a.)** ignore the escape characters; or **b.)** serialize the other characters which are necessary to escape.

Can anyone shed some light on, specifically, how to accomplish either of these?

**String Replacement Method**

```
public static string CheckValueOfProperty(string str)
{
    string trimmedString = str.Trim();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmedString))
        return null;
    else
    {
        // Commented out because the Serializer already transforms a '&' character into the appropriate escape character.
        //trimmedString = trimmedString .Replace("&", "&amp;");
        //trimmedString = trimmedString.Replace("<", "&lt;");
        //trimmedString = trimmedString.Replace(">", "&gt;");

        trimmedString = trimmedString.Replace("'", "&apos;");
        trimmedString = trimmedString.Replace("\"", "&quot;");

        return trimmedString;
    }
}
```

**XmlSerializer Code**

```
public static void SerializeAndOutput(object obj, string outputFilePath, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null)
{
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

    // If the Output File already exists, delete it.
    if (File.Exists(outputFilePath))
    {
        File.Delete(outputFilePath);
    }

    // Then, Create the Output File and Serialize the parameterized object as Xml to the Output File
    using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(outputFilePath))
    {
        if (ns == null)
        {
            x.Serialize(tw, obj);
        }
        else { x.Serialize(tw, obj, ns); }
    }

    // =====================================================================
    // The code below here is no longer needed, was used to force "utf-8" to 
    // UTF-8" to ensure the result was what was being expected.
    // =====================================================================
    // Create a new XmlDocument object, and load the contents of the OutputFile into the XmlDocument
    // XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument() { PreserveWhitespace = true };
    // xdoc.Load(outputFilePath);

    // Set the Encoding property of each XmlDeclaration in the document to "UTF-8";
    // xdoc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlDeclaration>().ToList().ForEach(d => d.Encoding = "UTF-8");

    // Save the XmlDocument to the Output File Path.
    // xdoc.Save(outputFilePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The single and double quote characters do not need to be escaped when used inside the node content in XML. The single quote or double quote characters only need to be escaped when used in a value of a node attribute. That's why the XMLSerializer does not escape them. And you also do not need to escape them.

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001878/do-i-need-to-replace-double-single-quote-in-xml-body-text) for reference.

---

BTW: The way you set the Encoding to UTF-8 afterwards, is awkward as well. You can specify the encoding with the StreamWriter and then the XMLSerializer will automatically use that encoding and also specify it in the XML declaration.

Comment: However, I do need to escape them when they are part of the actual value of the XML Element.  This is a requirement.  The `XmlSerializer` is properly escaping `&`, `>`, and `<` automatically when it appears as a value.  I also need to to escape single-quote and double-quote as well.

Comment: Where does your requirement come from? It is not a requirement of the XML standard.

Comment: it is a requirement of a third-party accepting the XML.  They require these characters to be escaped.

Comment: The encoding bit, doesn't appear to be necessary, but was originally done as a means to ensure the XML was 100% formatted the way it was expected.  The XML was expected to have "UTF-8" in the declaration, and was coming across as "utf-8".  While there is no difference between the two, we were receiving some errors, and had to rule out different avenues.  That particular bit of code will probably be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with. I have only tested it with a sample XML file and not the actual XML file I'm creating, so performance may take a hit; however, this seems to be working.

I'm reading the XML file line-by-line as a string, and replacing any of the defined "special" characters found in the string with their appropriate escape characters.  It should process in the order of the `specialCharacterList` `Dictionary<string, string>` variable, which means the `&` character should process first.  When processing `<`, `>` and `"` characters, it will only look at the value of the XML element.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace testSerializer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "testFile.xml";
        private static string tempFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "tempFile.xml";

        private static Dictionary<string, string> specialCharacterList = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"&","&amp;"}, {"<","&lt;"}, {">","&gt;"}, {"'","&apos;"}, {"\"","&quot;"}
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReplaceSpecialCharacters();
        }

        private static void ReplaceSpecialCharacters()
        {
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(tempFile))
            {
                foreach (string strLine in allLines)
                {
                    string newLineString = "";
                    string originalString = strLine;

                    foreach (var item in specialCharacterList)
                    {
                        // Since these characters are all valid characters to be present in the XML,
                        // We need to look specifically within the VALUE of the XML Element.
                        if (item.Key == "\"" || item.Key == "<" || item.Key == ">")
                        {
                            // Find the ending character of the beginning XML tag.
                            int firstIndexOfCloseBracket = originalString.IndexOf('>');

                            // Find the beginning character of the ending XML tag.
                            int lastIndexOfOpenBracket = originalString.LastIndexOf('<');

                            if (lastIndexOfOpenBracket > firstIndexOfCloseBracket)
                            {
                                // Determine the length of the string between the XML tags.
                                int lengthOfStringBetweenBrackets = lastIndexOfOpenBracket - firstIndexOfCloseBracket;

                                // Retrieve the string that is between the element tags.
                                string valueOfElement = originalString.Substring(firstIndexOfCloseBracket + 1, lengthOfStringBetweenBrackets - 1);

                                newLineString = originalString.Substring(0, firstIndexOfCloseBracket + 1) + valueOfElement.Replace(item.Key, item.Value) + originalString.Substring(lastIndexOfOpenBracket);
                            }
                        }
                        // For the ampersand (&) and apostrophe (') characters, simply replace any found with the escape.
                        else
                        {
                            newLineString = originalString.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
                        }

                        // Set the "original" string to the new version.
                        originalString = newLineString;
                    }

                    tw.WriteLine(newLineString);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```